# How to change JSON boolean to Yes or No with Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, return, boolean

Hey there I am new to javascript.

I am working with a API but can not convert the JSON boolean to YES or NO.

The boolean is at Phone that default is false. So I am trying to return false to "NO"

Here is my code:

```
        function loadCustomer(e) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', true);

        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                // console.log(this.responseText);

                const person = JSON.parse(this.responseText);


                const output = `
                    <ol>
                    <li>ID: ${person.userId}</li>
                    <li>Name: ${person.id}</li>
                    <li>Company: ${person.title}</li>
                    <li>Phone: ${person.completed}
                    </li>
                    </ol>
                `;

                document.getElementById('customer').innerHTML = output;
                // console.log(customer.completed);
                // if (customer.completed = false) {
                //     output.innerHTML = 'hey'
                // }

            }
        }

        xhr.send();
    }
```

Here is the JSON:

{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
  }

Comment: Use double equal sign to compare: if(customer.completed == false), otherwise, you're asigning false.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this :

```
<li>Phone: ${person.completed ? 'YES' : 'NO'}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display "YES" or "NO" instead of true and false, try:

```
    function loadCustomer(e) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', true);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            // console.log(this.responseText);

            const person = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            var phone = "NO";
            if (customer.completed) {
                phone = "YES";
            }
            const output = `
                <ol>
                <li>ID: ${person.userId}</li>
                <li>Name: ${person.id}</li>
                <li>Company: ${person.title}</li>
                <li>Phone: {PHONE}
                </li>
                </ol>
            `.replace(/{PHONE}/g, phone);

            document.getElementById('customer').innerHTML = output;
            // console.log(customer.completed);
            // if (customer.completed = false) {
            //     output.innerHTML = 'hey'
            // }

        }
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```